# Installing Different Versions of a Package

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am trying to use `apt-get` to install a specific version of amsynth. If I simply do

`sudo apt-get install amsynth`

It installs version 1.3. However I would like to install version 1.4. After searching the archive, it seems 1.4 is available http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=amsynth.

I've allowed the `universe` packages (using the information in [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)) and tried

`sudo apt-get install amsynth=1.4.2-2`

but the version cannot be found. How would I go about installing version 1.4?

**Note:** A potential solution is to install from https://launchpad.net/~nick-nickdowell/+archive/ubuntu/amsynth-master-daily.

However after running

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nick-nickdowell/amsynth-master-daily`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install amsynth`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

I still only have version 1.3 installed. The only clue I have as to why this doesn't work is that when running update I get in the console

`W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nick-nickdowell/amsynth-master-daily/ubuntu/dists/trust‌​y/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found`

Comment: Are you running 12.04 or 14.04?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you use? For 1.4 you need at least Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: I am running 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will not work. You are using Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04. How do you expect the system to know about the 1.4 version from a newer Ubuntu release?

If you want to install the newest version you could install from the personal archive https://launchpad.net/~nick-nickdowell/+archive/ubuntu/amsynth-master-daily Mind though: this will also probably uprade 1.3 to 1.4.

If you really want 1.3 and 1.4 together you need to install one of these from [source](https://code.google.com/p/amsynth/wiki/BuildingFromSource) so you can tell it to install in another directory.

---

You can pick "raring" as the latest release and version 1.4:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nick-nickdowell/amsynth-master-daily/ubuntu raring main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nick-nickdowell/amsynth-master-daily/ubuntu raring main 

Signing key:
    1024R/062A9BBC (What is this?) 
Fingerprint:
    D0BE1A6EB1A1DE103853721C1583CFE1062A9BBC
```

Comment: I only want version 1.4. I did try from the personal archive i.e. ran `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nick-nickdowell/amsynth-master-daily`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install amsynth` and finally `sudo apt-get upgrade`. But this still only installed version 1.3. The only clue I have is that when running update I see `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nick-nickdowell/amsynth-master-daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found` which maybe implies there is something wrong with the personal archive?

Comment: See http://ppa.launchpad.net/nick-nickdowell/amsynth-master-daily/ubuntu/dists/ Me does not see trusty amongst them :( Change your dist to "raring" :)